# Unity - UI Positions

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I currently have a problem on a UI.

The button on the phone moves when changing resolution and changes size as well. On the screenshots, it is in the General Panel. I also tried to put a second panel of the size of the phone, but it is all this panel that moves and changes size. How can I do, to keep the buttons at the right size and in place, as the background does when changing resolution?

Thanks in advance !

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the UI Scale Mode to "Scale With Screen Size".

THe Reference Resolution can help you place items in the editor. You can choose wether you want the width or the height (or a mixture) to be preferred when fitting the canvas to the resolution.

[image]

If you, for example, choose "Width" in the "Match" slider, the elements will never overshoot horizontally. This would be perfect for wrapping textfields.